# Configuring Android app settings via its website. Any pointers?

Tags: android

I need some guidance/tutorial links/code logic to know how can we use web to configure an android app installed on a non-rooted android phone.

Eg. Disable some functionality of the app by logging on to the app's website and disabling the setting. What trigger does the website send to the app and how does this get changed/stored on the app side. How does a web server initiate an action(http request) to the app?

I am more concerned about the android part of the code that the web.

Any pointers please ?

Comment: is it web app or normal app ??

Comment: im a newbiew so a lil confused. By web appp you mean an html5 app doing stuff in a browser? in that case, no. its a normal app(which has a backend authentication logic running on a web server). I just need to give the user the flexibility to change its settings both from the app as well as from the website once she's logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [c2dm](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/android/c2dm/) - it uses google servers to send message to a device.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that, it is direct violation of android permissions and also user privacy issue. So answer is, sorry not possible until phone is rooted and android OS permissions can be disabled.